# How to automate maven source generation for different projects?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have many projects is my EAR , and we have configured maven for automated source generation for each projects using eclipse "external tools configurations" (org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.programLaunchConfigurationType). 
But currently I have to go to "Run --> External Tools configuration" and run generate each sources manually one after another.

Is there any way I can automate this process, which will enable me to run these configurations one after another automatically ?

Comment: What kind of source generation? Preprocessor/annotation processor generation, or simply a compilation task?

Answer (score 0):

you can use multi module maven project and build project just by one click and then configure maven source generation as following

on parent pom use

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<name> foo - root </name>
<groupId>com.foo</groupId>
<artifactId>bar</artifactId>
<version>3.0.9</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

on childeren

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.9</version>
</parent>
```

and finally for source generation

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

look at [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) and [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/attach-source-javadoc-artifacts.html)

Comment: This is packaging the source into a jar but not generation of sources from whatever...

Comment: maven maven-source-plugin will do it

Comment: Sorry but the maven-source-plugin will only the package of the current src/ folder into a jar but does *not* generate any kind of source